# Переместить блок "Отложенные товары" в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет, есть Битрикс с шаблоном Aspro
[image: Карточка товара]

Нужно перенести кнопки, отложить и сравнить (на картинке они под цифрой 3) за пределы блока с фото.
Перенес. При нажатии на кнопку "Отложить" выскакивает ошибка отложенной корзины
Так же заметил что на родном месте у кнопки подменяется data-item. При переносе в другое место он не подменяется...

Comment: Возможно вы вынесли их за пределы своего компонента. Попробуйте перенести стилями.

Comment: переношу примерно на 20 строчек кода ниже, и уже не работает
в пределах одного компонента catalog.element

Comment: значит есть привязка к родительскому элементу. Переносите стилями или ищите js-код и дополнительно правте его